# Estimate the number of rows in an Excel file quickly

Tags: ruby, excel

I've got a Ruby + Merb webapp that needs to quickly estimate (or count exactly) how many row a spreadsheet has. It accepts every format that the [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/) library supports, including .xls, .xlsx, .ods, and text-based formats like CSV and TSV.

CSV/TSV is easy and fast:

```
`cat #{filepath} | dos2unix | wc -l`.to_i
```

However, using the roo library can be very slow for large files:

```
e = Excel.new(filepath)
e.last_row
```

My experience with Excel file formats is nil, so I'm appealing to the S.O. Masses: how might I try to estimate the number of rows an XLS, XLSX, or ODS file contains using only Ruby and/or standard UNIX programs? My goal is to be able to handle 5mb files in under 1.5 seconds (give or take on various hardware).

Answer (score 1):

Is this helpful? http://www.weheartcode.com/2007/10/05/reading-an-excel-file-with-ruby/

Comment: If I understand correctly, roo actually uses Parseexcel under the hood.

In either case, the problem is that reading in large Excel files (greater than a few hundred KB) takes way too much time, at least in Ruby. I imagine the solution will be to estimate the row count without properly reading and parsing the file -- perhaps by being able to grep for a row separator or identifier in the binary file format.

Comment: Sorry then .. apart from this, the only thing I can think of is checking out the xls file format http://www.wotsit.org/

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with [spreadsheet](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/) gem, give it a shot.